# Angular 2 dynamic style binding

Tags: css, angular, binding

I have the following Angular 2 component :

```
import { Component, Inject, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'generic-component',
    templateUrl: 'generic-component.component.html',
    styleUrls : ['generic-component.component.css']
 })
 export class GenericComponentComponent{    
    @Input() backCol: string = "#F0F8FF";  
    @Input() divClass: string = "myClass";
    ...
 }
```

with the template html :

```
<div class={{divClass}} [style.backgroundColor]="backCol">
    This is a div
</div>
```

The template renders correctly the div with the default backCol hex color variable, when the application starts.

But i would like to change the backCol variable string to another hex color afterwards, probably on an event.

On the **parent component** i have something like this:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <generic-component divClass={{myComp.divClass}} [style.backgroundCol]="myComp.backCol">
    </generic-component>
   `
})
export class ParentComp{
  myComp = new GenericComponentComponent();
}
onColorChange(){
  this.myComp.divClass = "mySecondClass";
  this.myComp.backCol = "#A22B11";
}
```

But the new color is not rendering onColorChange() call. All the other property bindings like divClass are updated and rendered correctly. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What is `myComp` supposed to be? What about `this.backCol = "#A22B11"`?

Comment: It is an instance of the GenericComponentComponent class. I use that instance to render a GenericComponentComponent into the parent's html template.

Comment: perhaps `this.instance.backCol = "#A22B11"` then? If not please provide more information (code) about what `myComp` is

Comment: Edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is not the correct way to get reference to the child component

```
export class ParentComp{
  myComp = new GenericComponentComponent();
}
```

You need to use @ViewChild to get hold of the reference to the child component:
In your Parent template:

```
<generic-component #child>
</generic-component>
```

Further more you don't need to pass the class and the style as an input. Since you can get reference to the child's properties using @ViewChild

In you parent component:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <generic-component #child>
    </generic-component>
   `
})
export class ParentComp{

    @ViewChild('child') myComp;

    onColorChange(){
      this.myComp.divClass = "mySecondClass";
      this.myComp.backCol = "#A22B11";
    }
}
```

**EDIT :** Updated plunkr with @ViewChildren example.
Example:
https://plnkr.co/edit/a0zddtEe0Q3No4mfaKQZ?p=preview

Comment: And what if i have an array of child components? I would like to be able to create a GenericComponentComponent Array inside the parent class.

Comment: You can use @ViewChildren('child1','child2','child3') childList:QueryList;

Comment: I think i get it now. I was binding only the properties and not updating the component instance itself, that's why i was unable to change the style, correct? Thank you!